# How to reactively run something on the server in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

It seems that most of the reactivity is on the client side.

I've got a server function that I need to run based on the number of items in a collection. The function creates a schema for an `OrderSubmissions` collection based on the number of documents in `Services`, which changes.

On the client this is easy - I simply do

```
/lib/schemas

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('services', function(){
    // re-creates OrderSubmissions schema any time the Services subscription returns different data
    });
  });
};
```

I could also rig up something with `Session` or `ReactiveVar`. Unfortunately, all of these techniques are only available to the client. I need to do:

```
/lib/schemas

if(Meteor.isServer){
  // re-creates OrderSubmissions schema any time Services collection changes
};
```

Is the only way to do this to use `.observe`? It seems like kind of an expensive thing to do. My `Services` collection will change very very infrequently (in fact, at this point all I want to do is create the `OrderSubmissions` schema in `/lib/schemas` when my `/server/fixtures.js` is done loading stuff into the `Services` collection.)

Unfortunately for my case, Meteor loads stuff in `/lib` before `/server`, so my schema in `/lib` is being created erroneously:

1. `/lib/schemas.js` runs and `OrderSubmissions` schema, which depends on `Services` to be populated, gets created erroneously on both the server and client because there is nothing in the `Services` collection.
2. `/server/fixtures.js` runs and populates the `Services` collection.

I need #2 to happen before #1, but #2 needs to stay in server code. I don't want to wrap it in `if(Meteor.isServer)` in `/lib` since it's not secure.

Comment: Can you put your code from /lib/schemas.js into a  `Meteor.startup(function() { });` ? I believe that would postpone execution until after your fixtures.js have run and populated `Services` collection.

Comment: As for server reactivity, I believe .observe and .observeChanges are the only options.

Answer (score 0):

If you add [peerlibrary:server-autorun](https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/server-autorun)

You could do the following on the server

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  // this code now reruns on the server if there is a reactive dependency enclosed here
})
```